# Show the nth occurrence of searched text

Tags: search, vim, vim-airline

I'm trying to find something that counts the number of responses when you do a search in a file `(using '/')`, so you know that you are looking at `3/10` results.

Is there anything like this out there? Perhaps an integration with airline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this plugin https://github.com/henrik/vim-indexed-search
it shows "Match 123 of 456 /search term/" in Vim searches

Answer (score 2):

```
:vim foo %
```

does just that:

```
(1 of 32): <the line containing the first match>
```

You can also do:

```
:%s/foo//n
```

which would output something like:

```
32 matches on 32 lines
```

---

Note that the first one only works reliably on a saved buffer.